# Apple ID - Want to make my xxx@icloud.com primary Apple ID?

Tags: icloud, apple-id

I recently created an `@icloud.com` address and now I would like to make that my default or primary address for my Apple ID instead of my current `@gmail.com` address.

I tried to change it through the **Manage Apple ID** page but it said 'Not use a domain used by Apple'.

Is it advisable to change my Apple ID from `@gmail.com` to `@icloud.com`?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Did you have a pre-existing Apple ID before you registered for iCloud?  Have you made purchases with that ID that you want to use and update moving forward?  What do you mean by *primary*? What exactly do you want to accomplish? Please help us to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't anything you can do with an iCloud.com Apple ID that you can't so with a gmail-based ID, if that's what you're asking. The reason you can't attach your new iCloud address to your existing gmail-based Apple ID account is that, as the previous poster indicated, every iCloud.com address automatically becomes its own independent Apple ID. And Apple, despite tons of interest from users, still won't let you merge two different Apple IDs.

You can, if you're interested, add your new iCloud based account and use it for email, Find Friends, iMessage, FaceTime, etc., while keeping your previous account tied to iTunes and the App Store. I've done it that way for years.

Answer (score 3):

This problem still exists to this day.  When you set up your Apple ID you are required to enter an already in-use email account that is not associated with an Apple domain.  This becomes your primary Apple ID email account.  From here you can then set up your @icloud.com account but you cannot set that @icloud.com address as the primary account address because Apple does not allow users to do so with Apple owned domains.

Not to be confusing, but you can set the @icloud.com address as your Apple ID.  To do so, just attempt to log into your primary email address a few times until you are prompted to go to iforgot dot apple.com.  From here just enter your @icloud.com address and select to verify account by answering security questions; do not use verify by email.  Once you successfully answer the security questions you will be prompted for a new password.  After that your @icloud.com address will become your default Apple ID, you can now access iCloud with the @icloud.com address, and you can now use the @iclould.com address for email.

Comment: I don't know if something changed since 2015, but I just followed these steps and it didn't change anything - my gmail address is still set as my AppleID, even though I can log in using my icloud address.

Answer (score 1):

In short, you don't need to worry about it. What is interesting is that your [xxx]@icloud.com is *automatically* a "primary" Apple ID. When you logged into appleid.apple.com, there should have been an "Alternate" Apple ID. This "Alternate" Apple ID has the same login capabilities, and password as your @gmail.com account has.

The important thing to note is that *these email addresses are basically synonymous*. You can log in anywhere (including appleid.apple.com) with your @icloud.com address that you can with your @gmail.com account. The password is the same.

I'm not sure why they do it this way, but it does allow another layer of protection against getting locked out of your account.

Comment: I'm not sure this is an accurate assessment of the situation. I suspect Jaimmin has *two* unique Apple IDs—just as I do. The question is confusing.

Comment: @jaberg, that is very possible, and if so, my answer is completely irrelevant. I will edit/delete when I see what the OP comes back with. Thanks for mentioning that.

Answer (score 0):

After messing with the accounts page for a month, I gave up.

I contacted Apple support to address this issue, but I don't think they know what I mean.

It looks like it's impossible to do so just with the account page, I suggest you contact Apple and have them do it for you. (If they could.)

Answer (score 0):

While this may not be what your looking for, you can use your xx@icloud.com to log into iCloud account. I like doing this when I get new device and/or resetting. It'll "look" like your xx@icloud.com email address is your [image]